# How to log my all updates of a page in php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

In my project I have a product add page and it has an edit option.

Added product details will goto the product table in mysql database.

I want to log all the editings which includes  the time and user it edits.

I done it by creating a  copy of table product as `product_updated`.

Whenever the product is edited, the product table value of that product is stored in the `product_updated` table with time and user updated.

Then  product table is updated with new values.

I'm done it in php mvc framework. My model has the following function.

This is worked,but it shows some error when product name contains `'` symbol.

What is the correct way to do this?

```
function product_edit_save($id = 0,$user_id) {


  $query=  $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id = $id");
  $result = $this->db->fetch_object($query);

    foreach ($result as $row) {

      $this->db->query("INSERT INTO product_updated SET product_id=$row->product_id,product_code = '$row->product_code', product_name =' $row->product_name', product_category = $row->product_category, 
     product_subcategory = $row->product_subcategory, product_supplier = ' $row->product_supplier', product_generic = $row->product_generic, 
         product_manufacturer  =$row->product_manufacturer,product_image = '$row->product_image', product_combination = $row->product_combination, product_package =$row->product_package,
             product_desc = '$row->product_desc', product_type = '$row->product_type', product_division = '$row->product_division',
                 product_chemical_name='$row->product_chemical_name',product_updatetime=now(),product_update_user=$user_id,product_banned=$row->product_banned", true);

    }

    $validate_form = true;
    $validate_error = array();
    $return['status'] = false;
    $return['message'] = '';

    if ($_POST) {

        $code = isset($_POST['code']) ? $_POST['code'] : '';
        $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
        $category = isset($_POST['category']) ? $_POST['category'] : '';
        $sub_category = isset($_POST['sub_category']) ? $_POST['sub_category'] : '';
        $generic = isset($_POST['generic']) ? $_POST['generic'] : '';
        $manufacturer = isset($_POST['manufacturer']) ? $_POST['manufacturer'] : '';
        $combination = isset($_POST['combination']) ? $_POST['combination'] : '';
        $package = isset($_POST['package']) ? $_POST['package'] : '';
        $desc = isset($_POST['desc']) ? $_POST['desc'] : '';
        $type = isset($_POST['type']) ? $_POST['type'] : '';
        $division = isset($_POST['division']) ? $_POST['division'] : '';
        $chemicalname = isset($_POST['chemicalname']) ? $_POST['chemicalname'] : '';
        $ban = isset($_POST['ban']) ? $_POST['ban'] : 0;

        if (isset($_POST['supplier'])) {
            $supplier = $_POST['supplier'];
        } else {
            $supplier = array();
        }



        if ($code == "") {
            $validate_error[] = "Code";
            $validate_form = false;
        } else {
            $esc_id = $this->db->escape($id);
            $esc_code = $this->db->escape($code);

            if ($this->db->num_rows($this->db->query("SELECT product_code FROM product WHERE product_code = $esc_code AND product_id != $esc_id")) != 0) {
                $validate_error[] = "Code Duplication";
                $validate_form = false;
            }
        }

        if ($name == "") {
            $validate_error[] = "Name";
            $validate_form = false;
        }


        if ($category == "-1") {
            $validate_error[] = "Category";
            $validate_form = false;
        }


        if ($manufacturer == "-1") {
            $validate_error[] = "Manufacturer";
            $validate_form = false;
        }


        if ($validate_form) {

            $esc_filename = $this->db->escape('');
            $isimage = "";
            if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {

                $this->library('upload');
                $image = $this->library['upload']->image($_FILES['image'], UPLOAD, '180');

                if ($image['status'] == 0) {
                    $validate_error[] = 'image ( ' . $image['message'] . ' )';
                    $validate_form = false;
                } else {
                    $esc_filename = $this->db->escape($image['filename']);
                    $isimage = ",product_image = $esc_filename";
                }
            } else {
                $isimage = "";
            }
        }



        if ($validate_form) {

            $esc_id = $this->db->escape($id);
            $sub_category = isset($_POST['sub_category']) ? $_POST['sub_category'] : '';
            $generic = isset($_POST['generic']) ? $_POST['generic'] : '';
            $manufacturer = isset($_POST['manufacturer']) ? $_POST['manufacturer'] : '';
            $combination = isset($_POST['combination']) ? $_POST['combination'] : '';
            $package = isset($_POST['package']) ? $_POST['package'] : '';
            $desc = isset($_POST['desc']) ? $_POST['desc'] : '';
            $type = isset($_POST['type']) ? $_POST['type'] : '';
            $division = isset($_POST['division']) ? $_POST['division'] : '';



            $esc_code = $this->db->escape($code);
            $esc_name = $this->db->escape(strtoupper($name));
            $esc_category = $this->db->escape($category);
            $esc_sub_category = $this->db->escape($sub_category);
            $esc_supplier = $this->db->escape(implode(",", $supplier));
            $esc_generic = $this->db->escape($generic);
            $esc_manufacturer = $this->db->escape($manufacturer);
            $esc_combination = $this->db->escape($combination);
            $esc_package = $this->db->escape($package);
            $esc_desc = $this->db->escape($desc);
            $esc_type = $this->db->escape(strtoupper($type));
            $esc_division = $this->db->escape(strtoupper($division));
            $esc_ban=$this->db->escape(strtoupper($ban));
            $esc_chemicalname = $this->db->escape($chemicalname);

            try {

                $this->db->transaction();

                $this->db->query("UPDATE product SET product_code = $esc_code, product_name = $esc_name, product_category = $esc_category,product_chemical_name=$esc_chemicalname, 
                product_subcategory = $esc_sub_category, product_supplier = $esc_supplier, product_generic = $esc_generic, 
                    product_manufacturer  = $esc_manufacturer, product_combination = $esc_combination, product_package = $esc_package, 
                        product_desc = $esc_desc $isimage,product_type = $esc_type, product_division = $esc_division,product_banned=$esc_ban WHERE product_id = $esc_id", true);

                $this->db->commit();

                $return['status'] = true;
                $return['message'] = "Successfully Updated";
                return $return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {

                $this->db->rollback();
                $return['message'] = "Failed to Update";
                return $return;
            }
        } else {

            $return['message'] = "Invalid Field " . implode(", ", $validate_error);
            return $return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` is deprecated.

Use `stripslashes()` to clean the variables and (optional) use `addslashes()` to add them back when reading them.

Example:

```
$supplier = stripslashes($_POST['supplier']);
```

As a sidenote, do not use `isset()`, use `!empty()`.

```
if(!empty($your_variable)) { ... }
```

instead of

```
if(isset($your_variable)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this or you should follow the best practices when it comes to prevention from SQL Injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

You could either use prepared statements (best option) or at least escape the data that you input in your SQL queries using mysqli_real_escape_string: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

This way a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name = 'test'data';
```

will become this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name = 'test\'data';
```

And you will stop getting errors.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks you for reminding me that, I changed it to mysqli equivalent.